# Stored Procedure OUTPUT param returns always NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I do have a problem. I am trying to return from the Stored procedure via OUTPUT parameter.

```
alter procedure dbo.UDP_GET_OUT
@P_PARAM XML OUTPUT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
BEGIN
SET @P_PARAM =
(
select 
name,system_type_id
from sys.types
FOR XML PATH('Type'),ROOT('ROOT'),ELEMENTS
)
/*SELECT @P_PARAM*/
END
```

Then I invoke the procedure and assign output param.

```
declare @xml XML
exec dbo.UDP_GET_OUT @xml
select @xml
```

Now the tricky part - the result is always NULL. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Must pass in the parameter as OUTPUT:

```
declare @xml XML;
exec dbo.UDP_GET_OUT @xml OUTPUT;
select @xml;
```